# Uninstall MSC Adams that doesn't have an unistaller

Tags: uninstall

I installed a CAE software : [MSC ADAMS](http://www.mscsoftware.com/Contents/Products/CAE-Tools/Adams.aspx) on Windows Xp pro. It installed fine in c:\msc.software\adams but doesn't appear in the Add-remove programs dialog. How do i uninstall it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/), it can uninstall 'most anything.

Comment: Does Revo work on windows 7?

Comment: probably, maybe

Answer (score 0):

The document [Installing MSC.ADAMS on Windows](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CBQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mscsoftware.com%2Fsupport%2Fprod_support%2Fadams%2Fdocumentation%2F2003%2Fdocs%2Finstallnt.pdf&ei=v1XrStGCFt_OjAfavKGcDQ&usg=AFQjCNFNrm_xr-cUhalMNIHlXqbPFYxKGA&sig2=2v4rUdDfgZuX4wOXA8shbA) says:

1. From the Start menu, point to MSC.Software, point to
   Programs, point to MSC.ADAMS 2003, and then select
   Uninstall ADAMS.
2. Follow the instructions on your screen to uninstall the
   MSC.ADAMS products. Select the Next button to
   continue through the installation.
   The installation program asks you to choose the type of
   uninstall you want to perform. You can select:
   ■ Automatic - Removes all MSC.ADAMS product
   files. It does not remove any files that you created in
   the installation directory.
   ■ Custom - Lets you select the files that you want to
   delete.
3. When the uninstall is complete, select Finish.

Does that work?

Comment: I'm using an older version actually : MD R2 Adams released 15 Nov 2006

Comment: (1) If you still have the installation, re-install to fix the Add-remove programs info, then uninstall. (2) If you don't have it, you can manually delete the MSC directory and Start menu, then use regedit to hunt for all occurrences of (a) the MSC directory and (b) of MSC (if not too many of them), and (carefully) delete. I think the main or only one will be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> MSC.Software.

Comment: Any good registry cleaner which can remove it ?

Comment: Revo Uninstaller is the best : http://www.revouninstaller.com/.